# IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'geckodriver.log'

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-app-engine, geckodriver

I am trying to run a python script by clicking a button on HTML page. Python script uses Selenium Firefox driver to perform some tasks. The script works well when I run it from command prompt but when I try to run it through webpage withing the application. It gives the following error.

```html
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime\stubs.py", line 278, in __init__
    raise IOError(errno.EROFS, 'Read-only file system', filename)
IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'geckodriver.log'
```

I am using Google App Engine's webapp2 framework and python 2.7

I tried to googling it but couldn't find anything. Any suggestions please, how can I solve this bug.

Comment: **Selenium Firefox driver** and ***C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\*** ? Am I missing something?

Comment: App Engine won't let you write to disk, and it looks like selenium is trying to do this.

Comment: The geckodriver creates a log file in the current directory, but in your case the directory doesn't have the permissions. So either give the permissions, or change the current directory.

Comment: @DebanjanB I am not sure what do you mean by that.

Comment: @jaspreetsohal My question is simple, why would you force _GeckoDriver_ try to read/access/write within `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, App Engine applications are run in a sandboxed environment. One of those sandbox conditions is that you are not permitted to modify the filesystem.

In normal circumstances, you can get around this by configuring Selenium to write the logs to `/dev/null` by setting the `BROWSER_LOGFILE` environment variable to `/dev/null`. I'm not sure if that'll run into the same filesystem issues, but it's probably worth a shot.

Answer (score 3):

As others have commented, the problem is a lack of permissions in the current path.

However, the log can be stored either inside the **/tmp** folder [1] or using **/dev/null**. It can be done with this python lines:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

your_executable_path = "/tmp/geckodriver"
# Or using webdriver_manager [2]
# from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
# your_executable_path = GeckoDriverManager(path="/tmp").install()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=your_executable_path, log_path='/tmp/geckodriver.log')
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
```

Keep in mind that **it is required to have installed the browser** into the system. [3]

- [1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files
- [2] https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/
- [3] https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by disabling the logs in the following way:

`driver = webdriver.Firefox(service_log_path='/dev/null')`